# Xamarin Forms ScrollView breaks application

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I am trying to wrap my XAML page in a scroll view, the page works fine on it's own (android 4.4 up to 8) but when I introduce the scroll I get the following error over and over in the device log:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
04-13 10:20:07.633  Samsung SM-T230 Error   144 BufferQueue [com.glmobileapp/md5dc496626c370b103ce86ee6c362b5772.MainActivity] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (1) exceeded (dequeued=2 undequeudCount=0)
```

along with the following in the output window:

```
04-13 10:27:10.966 D/skia    ( 1117): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
04-13 10:27:11.026 I/dalvikvm-heap( 1117): Clamp target GC heap from 516.602MB to 512.000MB
04-13 10:27:11.026 D/dalvikvm( 1117): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 511501K/513364K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
04-13 10:27:11.026 I/dalvikvm-heap( 1117): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 22473160-byte allocation
04-13 10:27:11.076 I/dalvikvm-heap( 1117): Clamp target GC heap from 516.602MB to 512.000MB
04-13 10:27:11.076 D/dalvikvm( 1117): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 1% free 511500K/513364K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
04-13 10:27:11.076 E/dalvikvm-heap( 1117): Out of memory on a 22473160-byte allocation.
04-13 10:27:11.076 I/dalvikvm( 1117): "Thread-7288" prio=10 tid=15 RUNNABLE
04-13 10:27:11.076 I/dalvikvm( 1117):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41e27160 self=0x815faa88
04-13 10:27:11.076 I/dalvikvm( 1117):   | sysTid=1176 nice=-11 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-2103463040
04-13 10:27:11.076 I/dalvikvm( 1117):   | state=R schedstat=( 4785797128 1283386243 1816 ) utm=437 stm=41 core=3
04-13 10:27:11.076 I/dalvikvm( 1117):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-13 10:27:11.076 I/dalvikvm( 1117):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
04-13 10:27:11.076 I/dalvikvm( 1117):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
04-13 10:27:11.076 I/dalvikvm( 1117):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:541)
04-13 10:27:11.076 I/dalvikvm( 1117):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:571)
04-13 10:27:11.076 I/dalvikvm( 1117):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I see 'scaled bitmap' mentioned, I have one large png only.
Any idea how I should go about debugging / fixing?

UPDATE:

I replaced image with ffimageloading:CachedImage, it no longer breaks the app but it now shows a blank screen

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="gl_mobile_app.Views.Article.ArticlePage"
             xmlns:artina="clr-namespace:UXDivers.Artina.Shared;assembly=UXDivers.Artina.Shared"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:gl_mobile_app.Views.Templates;assembly=gl_mobile_app"
             xmlns:ratio="clr-namespace:gl_mobile_app;assembly=gl_mobile_app"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:gl_mobile_app.Controls;assembly=gl_mobile_app"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
              >
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Back" Clicked="GoBack" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="#ede8db" x:Name="articleGrid" Padding="0,0,0,0" >

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="47.5*" x:Name="grdRow0" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="5*" x:Name="grdRow1"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="47.5*" x:Name="grdRow2" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ratio:ContentRatioContainer Grid.Row="0" x:Name="imgContainer" >
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage Aspect="AspectFill" Source="KevingroveCarouselImg.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="bigImg" 
                            HeightRequest="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=880, LandscapePhone=125, PortraitTablet=600, LandscapeTablet=400 }" Grid.Row="0"/>
                </ratio:ContentRatioContainer>
                <artina:Button Margin="10,10,10,10" x:Name="ImgZoom" Clicked="EnlargeImage" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" Image="IncreaseImageIcon.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"/>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#ede8db" Margin="0" Padding="30,0,30,0" x:Name="iconStack" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.TOILET}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Black" FontSize ="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=25, LandscapePhone=18, PortraitTablet=30, LandscapeTablet=20 }" />
                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.WHEELCHAIR}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Black" FontSize ="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=25, LandscapePhone=18, PortraitTablet=30, LandscapeTablet=20 }" />
                    <Label x:Name="expand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="{x:Static ratio:FontAwesome.ARROW_DOWN}" Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=25, LandscapePhone=18, PortraitTablet=30, LandscapeTablet=20 }" />
                </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout x:Name="TopLayout" Padding="30,0,30,0" BackgroundColor="Green">

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="MapMarker" Opacity="0.0">
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.MAP_MARKER}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" WidthRequest="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=30,PortraitTablet=50, LandscapeTablet=50 }" />
                            <Label Text="Address" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold"  />
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout x:Name="AddressStack" >
                            <StackLayout.Padding>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="34.5,0,0,0" Android="34.5,0,0,0" />
                                    </OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="54.5,0,0,0" Android="54.5,0,0,0" />
                                    </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </StackLayout.Padding>
                            <Label x:Name="AddressLabel" >
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="HelveticaNeue-Roman" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeue-Roman.otf#HelveticaNeue-Roman" />
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="Empty1" HeightRequest="10" />

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="clock" Opacity="0.0">
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.CLOCK}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" WidthRequest="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=30,PortraitTablet=50, LandscapeTablet=50 }"/>
                            <Label Text="Opening Times" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout x:Name="OpeningTimesStack">
                            <StackLayout.Padding>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="34.5,0,0,0" Android="34.5,0,0,0" />
                                    </OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="54.5,0,0,0" Android="54.5,0,0,0" />
                                    </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </StackLayout.Padding>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" x:Name="OpeningTimesLabel" >
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="HelveticaNeue-Roman" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeue-Roman.otf#HelveticaNeue-Roman" />
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="Empty2" HeightRequest="10" />

                        <StackLayout x:Name="txt" Opacity="1.0">
                            <Label x:Name="header" Style="{ StaticResource HeaderStyle }" />
                            <Label x:Name="description" FontSize="Large" />
                        </StackLayout>

                        <ListView  x:Name="ArticleListView" CachingStrategy="RetainElement" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <local:ArticleContentItemTemplate />
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to optimize the png , verify the size because as it's mentioned

```
Clamp target GC heap from 516.602MB to 512.000MB
```

you app huge memory so the device can't allocate more memory for the app that's why

Comment: thanks, updated post to say I'm now using ffimageloading:CachedImage, so no more crash but nothing showing on screen

Comment: Updated post with XAML

Comment: try Source="KevingroveCarouselImg" i'm not sure but i work without extension

Comment: No joy, same thing I'm afraid

Comment: What's the size of the picture ?

Comment: The image is actually determined via code behind and changes depending on the previous page, all are of similar size, this one is 1296 x 888

Comment: the size in mb !

Comment: Ah sorry! 2.05MB

Comment: it's not a very big size it should work , can you try out of the scroll view even in a new page without grid or aything and a simple  balise with any height and width values make it very simple just for testing , i think that picture is showing  but it covered with smth !

Comment: Yes the picture (the whole page in fact) works just fine, it' when I wrap everything in a scroll that it breaks